# How do you link Bootstrap icons to links on Ruby?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, hyperlink

Hi I'm currently trying to link a Bootstrap icon link along with its respective text to a certain link. Currently, I tried wrapping the svg tag with single quotes, but that just gives me the string.

Currently my code is like this:

```
        <li class="nav-item d-flex flex-column">
            
            <a href="#" class=class="nav-link d-flex flex-column">
                        
                    <span class="nav-link px-5" href="#"><%= link_to 'Leaderboard', teams_path %></span>

                    <%= link_to '<svg width="2em" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-flag-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.5 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v13a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-13a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.762 2.558C4.735 1.909 5.348 1.5 6.5 1.5c.653 0 1.139.325 1.495.562l.032.022c.391.26.646.416.973.416.168 0 .356-.042.587-.126a8.89 8.89 0 0 0 .593-.25c.058-.027.117-.053.18-.08.57-.255 1.278-.544 2.14-.544a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5c-.638 0-1.18.21-1.734.457l-.159.07c-.22.1-.453.205-.678.287A2.719 2.719 0 0 1 9 9.5c-.653 0-1.139-.325-1.495-.562l-.032-.022c-.391-.26-.646-.416-.973-.416-.833 0-1.218.246-2.223.916A.5.5 0 0 1 3.5 9V3a.5.5 0 0 1 .223-.416l.04-.026z"/>
                    </svg>', teams_path %>
                    
            </a>
        </li>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

```
<%= link_to teams_path do %>
  <svg width="2em" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-flag-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.5 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v13a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-13a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.762 2.558C4.735 1.909 5.348 1.5 6.5 1.5c.653 0 1.139.325 1.495.562l.032.022c.391.26.646.416.973.416.168 0 .356-.042.587-.126a8.89 8.89 0 0 0 .593-.25c.058-.027.117-.053.18-.08.57-.255 1.278-.544 2.14-.544a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5c-.638 0-1.18.21-1.734.457l-.159.07c-.22.1-.453.205-.678.287A2.719 2.719 0 0 1 9 9.5c-.653 0-1.139-.325-1.495-.562l-.032-.022c-.391-.26-.646-.416-.973-.416-.833 0-1.218.246-2.223.916A.5.5 0 0 1 3.5 9V3a.5.5 0 0 1 .223-.416l.04-.026z"/>
  </svg>
<% end %>
```